# LG G3 digitizer not reporting movements smoothly

Tags: screen, touchscreen, lg-g3

I just replaced the LCD/digitizer assembly on my LG G3, and the new digitizer is behaving strangely. When I scroll views in apps, they jerk a few pixels at a time rather than moving smoothly. The actual scrolling is smooth; if I scroll quick and let go, then it decelerates smoothly. As long as my finger is in contact, though, it's as though the scrolling has a series of detents that it briefly pauses at. At first, I thought it was that it was operating at a lower resolution than the pixels on the screen, but I've found that these detents occur in any direction, not independently on the X and Y axes. It is almost as if it has some sort of built-in hysteresis, where it won't report a position update until the touch has moved at least a certain distance from the last report. I've never encountered anything like this with the phone in the past, including with a previous replacement LCD/digitizer assembly of the same type from the same supplier.

I've recorded a video of this in action, with the "Show touch data" Developer option enabled:

https://youtu.be/-3N-2uft00w

You can see how there are regular intervals in which the X/Y coordinates displayed at the top of the screen don't update even though my finger is moving -- as though it is only reporting an update every 20 pixels or something.

Is this something I can fix, or is this likely a hardware problem with the new digitizer, and if I want my smooth scrolling back I'm going to have to get it replaced again?

Comment: I am actually experiencing the exact same issue after replacing my screen. I'm using CM14.1. Did you manage to fix the issue or find out what it was? Also, which supplier did you use?

Comment: I did not find a solution. The supplier was Sunsky. I actually ordered 3 from them, and the first two worked fine, though were perhaps a bit fragile (they developed cracks without any manhandling that I am aware of). I don't know why the third one was different -- different batch? different manufacturer? or simply manufacturing defect? In any event, it reached a point where paying the early upgrade fee with my carrier was cheaper than trying one more replacement, so I'm now using an LG G5 and anxiously awaiting root on it. :-)